# What is the ($n$-dimensional) Fourier transform of $f(a_1 x_1, ..., a_nx_n)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am learning Fourier transform and I was wondering 
what the Fourier transform of $f(a_1 x_1, ..., a_nx_n)$ is with respect to $\hat{f}$? I could only find answers for the one dimensional case and I was wondering how this worked for $n$-dimensional. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It scales pretty much how you'd imagine it would.

Suppose we have the Fourier transform of $f$, given by:
$$
\mathscr{F}_f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  f(t_1,\ldots,t_n)
\exp\left(-2\pi i\sum\limits_j x_jt_j \right)
\,dt_1 \ldots \,dt_n
$$
Let the scaled function be $\widetilde{f}=f(a_1t_1,\ldots,a_nt_n)$.
Then we get:
\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}_\widetilde{f}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) 
&= 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  f(a_1t_1,\ldots,a_nt_n)
\exp\left(-2\pi i\sum\limits_j x_jt_j \right)
\,dt_1 \ldots \,dt_n \\
&=
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  f(a_1t_1,\ldots,a_nt_n)
\exp\left(-2\pi i\sum\limits_j \frac{x_j}{a_j}
\underbrace{t_ja_j\displaystyle}_{v_j\displaystyle}\displaystyle \right)\displaystyle
\,\frac{dv_1}{|a_1|} \ldots \,\frac{dv_n}{|a_n|} \\
&=
\left[
\prod\limits_k \frac{1}{|a_k|}
\right]
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  f(v_1,\ldots,v_n)
\exp\left(-2\pi i\sum\limits_j \frac{x_j}{a_j} v_j \right)
\,dv_1 \ldots \,dv_n \\
&=
\left[
\prod\limits_k \frac{1}{|a_k|}
\right]\mathscr{F}_f\left(\frac{x_1}{a_1},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{a_n}\right)
\end{align}
which is the analogue of the 1D case.
This can be considered a *Similarity Theorem* for a Fourier Transform.